# Можно ли убрать кучу повторяющей информации в SQL*Plus консоли?

Tags: sql, oracle, форматирование, sqlplus

Возможно ли, когда выводишь информацию в консоли убрать повторяющиеся имена колонок и черточек (--) после каждого вывода информации столбца?

Или лучше уже использовать SQL Developer для большого количества строк?

Пример, что мне выдает при выводе информации о пользователе (инф. которую я попытался получить в консоли взял в такие вот звездочки для Вашего лучшего просмотра (****)):

```
EMPLOYEE_ID
-----------
FIRST_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LAST_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMAIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PHONE                                              HIRE_DATE MANAGER_ID
-------------------------------------------------- --------- ----------
JOB_TITLE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         **98**

EMPLOYEE_ID
-----------
FIRST_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LAST_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMAIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PHONE                                              HIRE_DATE MANAGER_ID
-------------------------------------------------- --------- ----------
JOB_TITLE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**Amber**

EMPLOYEE_ID
-----------
FIRST_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LAST_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMAIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PHONE                                              HIRE_DATE MANAGER_ID
-------------------------------------------------- --------- ----------
JOB_TITLE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**Rose**

EMPLOYEE_ID
-----------
FIRST_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LAST_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMAIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PHONE                                              HIRE_DATE MANAGER_ID
-------------------------------------------------- --------- ----------
JOB_TITLE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**amber.rose@example.com**

EMPLOYEE_ID
-----------
FIRST_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LAST_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMAIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PHONE                                              HIRE_DATE MANAGER_ID
-------------------------------------------------- --------- ----------
JOB_TITLE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**650.507.9822                                       23-MAY-16         25**

EMPLOYEE_ID
-----------
FIRST_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LAST_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMAIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PHONE                                              HIRE_DATE MANAGER_ID
-------------------------------------------------- --------- ----------
JOB_TITLE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**Shipping Clerk**

EMPLOYEE_ID
-----------
FIRST_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LAST_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMAIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PHONE                                              HIRE_DATE MANAGER_ID
-------------------------------------------------- --------- ----------
JOB_TITLE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

UPD вывода:

```
SQL> set lines 999 pages 100
SQL> select * from employees fetch next 10 rows only;

EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME

                                            LAST_NAME

                                                                            EMAIL

                                                                                                            PHONE
                                               HIRE_DATE MANAGER_ID
----------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- --------- ----------
JOB_TITLE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         98 Amber

                                            Rose

                                                                            amber.rose@example.com

                                                                                                            650.507.9822                                       23-MAY-16         25
Shipping Clerk

         99 Bella

                                            Stone

                                                                            bella.stone@example.com

                                                                                                            650.507.9833                                       21-JUN-16         25
Shipping Clerk

        100 Thea

                                            Hawkins

                                                                            thea.hawkins@example.com

                                                                                                            650.5
```

Comment: Вопрос не по теме: Почему вы никогда не голосуете? Из вашего профиля: _Участник не отдал ни одного голоса_ . На сег.день вы задали 28 вопросов, и получается, что вы считаете, ответы на них невысокого качества, пользы от них мало. Или есть какая-то другая причина неучастия в голосовании? Заметьте, что голосовать за сообщения вы не обязаны, и данный комментарий ни в коем случае не является упрёком, просто интересна причина.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно. Так сразу после подключения:

```
SQL> select * from  hr.employees fetch first 10 rows only;

EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME
----------- -------------------- -------------------------
EMAIL                     PHONE_NUMBER         HIRE_DATE JOB_ID         SALARY
------------------------- -------------------- --------- ---------- ----------
COMMISSION_PCT MANAGER_ID DEPARTMENT_ID
-------------- ---------- -------------
        100 Steven               King
SKING                     515.123.4567         17-JUN-03 AD_PRES         24000
                                     90

[... и так ещё 9 строк]
```

С указанием допустимой [длины](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-6C9EC78E-F27C-4588-A400-FE8732871B40) строки и [страницы](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-6DB11E90-9B72-4100-8A8A-BF9BD345D0EB) будет несколько лучше:

```
SQL> set lines 999 pages 100
SQL> /

EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                 EMAIL                     PHONE_NUMBER         HIRE_DATE JOB_ID         SALARY COMMISSION_PCT MANAGER_ID DEPARTMENT_ID
----------- -------------------- ------------------------- ------------------------- -------------------- --------- ---------- ---------- -------------- ---------- -------------
        100 Steven               King                      SKING                     515.123.4567         17-JUN-03 AD_PRES         24000                                      90
        101 Neena                Kochhar                   NKOCHHAR                  515.123.4568         21-SEP-05 AD_VP           17000                       100            90
        102 Lex                  De Haan                   LDEHAAN                   515.123.4569         13-JAN-01 AD_VP           17000                       100            90
[... ещё 7 строк]

10 rows selected.
```

Разумеется, можно указывать имена нужных колонок вместо `select *`.

---

SQL*Plus не подсчитывает динамически фактическую длину значений символьных колонок, а берёт их макс. длину из метаданных. Никакой опции, чтобы ограничить ширину отображения для всех символных столбцов нет.

Макс. длина символьных столбцов в таблице из вопроса - 255 символов. Чтобы задать приемлимую ширину их отображения, то надо выполнить команду [COL[UMN]](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/COLUMN.html#GUID-643B665F-B134-4A0B-88F7-10400D6D199E) для всех столбцов в листе запроса. Например:

```
SQL> create table emp as
    select cast ('name' as varchar2 (255)) name, cast ('memo' as varchar2 (255)) memo  
    from dual
/
SQL> select * from emp
/
NAME                                                                                                                                                                                                            MEMO
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
name                                                                                                                                                                                                            memo

SQL> col name for a8
SQL> col memo for a8
SQL> /

NAME     MEMO
-------- --------
name     memo
```

Comment: Вроде бы результат хочет вывестись правильно, но сами столбцы таблиц оставляют много -------------- У Вас в примере оно не пишет много их. Не подскажите как можно их убрать. 
Пишу запрос так: 
`SQL>  select * from employess fetch next 10 rows only;
 SQL> set lines 999 pages 100`

Comment: Не совсем понял, почему вы `set lines 999 pages 100` пишете после запроса? В примере оно ДО запроса. `/` это повторный запуск ранее набранного запроса, вот теперь его наберите.

Comment: Прикрепил к своему вопросу* в UPD как мне выводит с многими -----

Comment: А  какая у вас версия?  У вас что-то с длиной колонки FIRST_NAME. Попробуйте: `col FIRST_NAME for a16` и повторите запрос.

Comment: 19c. После  `col FIRST_NAME for a16` колонка last_name вернулась наверх к first_name

Comment: 19c БД, или клиент тоже?

Comment: Вроде как да. После делания того же к last_name `col LAST_NAME for a16` столбец EMAIL вернулся наверх к ним. 
Можно ли как-то для всех стандарт сделать ?

Comment: А какие у вас макс. длины столбцов? Посмотрел, у вас  все символьные столбцы  255 символов. Это так? Тогда только набиратъ для всех `col colname format a<длина>`. Никакой опции, чтобы все укоротить нет. SQL*Plus не подсчитывает динамически фактическую длину символьных строк, а берёт длину из метаданных. Если там стоит 255, он и отображает 255. Естественно полная длина не помещается в 999 и вывод расползается на несколько строк.

Comment: У меня стандарная схема HR, и там столбцы длиной 20-25 байт, они и отображаются нормально. Ну вообще то для разработки SQL\*Plus не совсем подходит.  Скрипт запустить, что-то быстро поправить - это да, но т.е. набирать в нём сложные запросы довольно мучительно. Посмотрите в сторону SQLcl, он  в коробке поставляется. У него тоже консольный интерфейс, но он посовременней и в будущем должен заменить SQL\*Plus. В нём проблемы с длиной столбцов не будет, т.к. он подсчитывает её динамически.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы! Буду знать теперь.

Comment: Рад был помочь. Извините, что нужной опции нету, но тут я же не виноват.

Comment: Ничего, SQL Developer уже или как Вы сказали SQLcl можно исп.

Comment: SQL Developer и SQLcl это одно и тоже. У последнего просто GUI убрали, и добиваются полной совместимости с SQL\*Plus, т.е. чтобы старые скрипты с ним работали без ошибок.

Answer (score 3):

> Или лучше уже использовать SQL Developer для большого количества строк?

SQL*Plus подходит для администрирования, запуска скриптов, несложных однострочных запросов. Но для разработки он не совсем подходит, т.к. набрать в нём сложный запрос для того, чтобы выполнить его один-два раза, довольно непросто. На смену ему Oracle готовит [SQLcl](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/sql-developer-command-line/19.4/sqcug/working-sqlcl.html#GUID-1343FA2B-BDB4-4645-B4D4-CD7C3E200AC9), который поставляется в коробке, `$ORACLE_HOME/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/README.md`:

> Oracle SQL Developer Command Line (SQLcl) is a free command line interface for Oracle Database.
> It allows you to interactively or batch execute SQL and PL/SQL.
> SQLcl provides in-line editing, statement completion, and command recall for a feature-rich experience, all while also supporting your previously written SQL*Plus scripts.

Простым языком, SQLcl это SQL Developer без GUI, который полностью совместим с SQL*Plus.

В нём проблемы с отображением [длинных символьных столбцов](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/sql-developer-command-line/19.4/sqcug/working-sqlcl.html#GUID-E1EB4D88-D268-400E-BFA3-11F6F4755527) не будет:

> The ansiconsole option formats and resizes data according to the column widths, for easier readability.

```
$ sql iam/iam@server/pdb1

SQLcl: Release 19.4 Production on Sun Aug 02 15:40:55 2020

SQL> desc emp
Name Null? Typ
---- ----- --------------
NAME       VARCHAR2(2000)
MEMO       VARCHAR2(2000)

SQL> select * from emp;

NAME
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MEMO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
memo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

SQL> set sqlformat ansiconsole
SQL> / 
/
   NAME    MEMO
_______ _______
name    memo
```

Или визуально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]